# What is the specific function of PROMPT and ECHO alongside an ACCEPT statement in COBOL

Tags: cobol, microfocus

I was looking through some source code for a RM/COBOL program and I keep running into ACCEPT statements similar to this:

```
   ACCEPT field-name LINE 23, POSITION 75 PROMPT ECHO
```

There are similar ACCEPT statements like this one that functions as input fields but have no PROMPT ECHO alongside them.

So my question is: What is the functionality of the PROMPT ECHO?

Thanks,
Chubonga93

Answer (score 2):

I can help, i use `ECHO` everyday, is simple as this: Whenever the `ACCEPT` statement is run, **it shows the current value of the identifier**.

Say, you have this picture:

```
01 WS_NAME PIC X(20) VALUE "Chubonga".
```

And this `ACCEPT`:

```
DISPLAY "Enter name:".
ACCEPT WS_NAME ECHO.
```

The program will prompt:

```
Enter name:
Chubonga
```

If you change the value of `WS_NAME` at execution time and the `ACCEPT` is rerun, it will show the new value of said identifier.

---

Edit: Depending on the compiler, it may or may not echo back the value if it was set by `VALUE` instead of `MOVE` or previous `ACCCEPT`.

Comment: Then if I type `BILL` I get `BILLONGA`? Can you expand on that?

Comment: No, whatever you type becomes the new value. If you type `BILL` it will display `BILLONGA` until you press Enter/Return. When you press Enter/Return the new value -however- will be `BILL` and also, `BILL` will be displayed at the `ACCEPT` position.
`ECHO` is a very strange statement indeed.

Comment: Ah cool. So it's like a placeholder in HTML then. Thanks for the helpful tip, Molusco. I would upvote but not enough reps

Answer (score 1):

From Micro Focus's documentation (of their support for RM/COBOL's) [PROMPT clause](http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/sx50/lhpdf50n.htm):

> The PROMPT clause causes the empty character positions in the screen item to be marked on the screen during an ACCEPT operation while the system is ready to accept operator-keyed data into that item.

The general format is

> PROMPT [CHARACTER IS { identifier-1, literal-1 } ]

which doesn't account for your ECHO keyword.  But this [compatibility guide entr](http://supportline.microfocus.com/documentation/books/sx2011sp1/cgrmci.htm#s025)y alludes to the `ECHO` keyword:

> 5.2.14 Display of Input Data in Concealed ACCEPT Fields
>
> If you have specified OFF and ECHO clauses for the same ACCEPT statement in your program, the RM/COBOL system will conceal any data entered during input for that statement but on completion of input will display the data. This COBOL system, however, will not display the data for this ACCEPT statement once input has been completed.
>   Solution:
>
> If you wish to display the data input for an ACCEPT statement with the OFF and ECHO clauses specified, you must add a DISPLAY statement after the ACCEPT statement.

I see several references online that document `NO ECHO` (which has the effect that the user's input is not displayed to the screen) but nothing firm for `ECHO`.  I suspect that it has no effect in your case, that is, that the user's input is echoed as usual.

Comment: Ah I see. Just to make sure I read it right. The PROMPT basically converts the empty characters into spaces?

Comment: In your case, since there is no `CHARACTER` keyword, I think that it fills in the response area with copies of a default character, which might be configured in your system as a whole, or with a compile-time option.  And the default default is probably a space character.